# load bootstrap modal on typing /admin on url

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, codeigniter-2

I don't know how to load a modal window without leaving the home page, if my url is "http://www.example.com/main/" . I would like to launch a login modal when i write  "http://www.example.com/main/admin" <-- in the url.
 i'm using codeigniter, main is the controller ,  admin is the method but i don't know how to trigger the modal since i'm not clicking neither on button nor link.

```
function method(){

$this->load->view('login');   // login file that have login modal window code.

}
```

thanks

Comment: `http://www.example.com/main/admin#modal` have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

To open a Bootstrap Modal on page load (not necessary to click a link or button). You can use the following jquery snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```

`#modal` is the div that contains data for modal.